# How to replace pandas append with concat?

Tags: python, pandas

Can you help me replace append with concat in this code?

```
saida = pd.DataFrame()
for x, y in lCodigos.items():
try:
    df = consulta_bc(x)
    logging.info(f'Indice {y} lido com sucesso.')
except Exception as err:
    logging.error(err)
    logging.warning('Rotina Indice falhou!')
    exit()
df['nome'] = y
saida = saida.append(df)   
print(saida)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just save the "dataframe parts" using a list and use [`pd.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) on that list of dataframes at the end:

```py
saida = list()  # Now use a list
for x, y in lCodigos.items():
    # ... your original code
    saida.append(df)
saida = pd.concat(saida)  # You can now create the dataframe
```

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Py/Postgres/Vers3/xlogIND3.py", line 35, in <module>
    saida = saida.append(df)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'append'

Comment: Sorry, fixed it. The problem was redefining `saida` at the end of each loop (should not be done)

Answer (score 3):

`saida= pd.concat([saida, df], axis= 1)`

**the above☝️ should work in place of the following**
(set axis=0 if you'd like to place the dataframes 'on top of each other')

`saida= saida.append(df)`

Comment: axis=0 is correct.

Answer (score 0):

It didn't work in my system. After getting the list:

```py
saidaAdd = pd.DataFrame(saida)  # now you have the dataframe

FullFile = concat(['original_file', saidaAdd], axis =0)
# is probably what was intended to build records
```